# I have multiple github webhooks configured to a single webhook. Is there a way to trigger only one webhook at a time?

Tags: github, webhooks

I have multiple github webhooks configured to a single webhook. Is there a way  to trigger only one webhook at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting up a GitHub Action, using [`workflow-webhook-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-webhook-action)

You can then call said action with parameters, and make that action call in turn call a remote webhook endpoint with a JSON or form-urlencoded payload, and support for BASIC authentication.

That JSON or form-urlencoded payload can include a parameter which will help your listener decide which local webhook to call/forward to.